# error when calling-jquery-function-on-datalist-button-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

calling-jquery-function-on-datalist-button-click. the error when i click on the button in another row
open the first div all buttons when i click open the first div for first row only please i need help.

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
                $("#shoow").toggle('slow');
            }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<asp:DataList ID="dtlRoomsPrice" Visible="false" orizontalAlign="center" runat="server"
    ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" Width="700px" OnItemDataBound="dtlRoomsDetails_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table id="RoomList" style="width: 700px;" border="0" align="left">
            <%
                RowCount++;
                if (UsingRows.IndexOf(RowCount.ToString()) != -1)
                {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td width="215" style="border: solid 1px #BDC7D8;">
                    <table border="0" id="LeftTable" width="190" border="0" align="left">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="shbe_h2" colspan="2">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_label" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.RoomType") %>'
                                    Width="190px"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="LabelGr" Visible="false" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_label" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.GuaranteeRequired") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 55px;">
                                <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
                                    <asp:Image Width="50" ID="RoomImg" runat="server" Height="50" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ImageRoomCode") %>' />
                                    <span>
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="370" Height="246" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ImageRoomCode") %>' /></span>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: left;">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="toggleDiv('shoow'); return false; " runat="server">ShowDetails</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAmiintiesTxt" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_label" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,Amenities %>"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAmiinties" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_h2" Text='<%# Eval("Amenities") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="LblRoomDesc" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_h2" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.RoomText") %>'
                                    Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCanclText" Width="130" runat="server" CssClass="shbe_label" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Payment and Cancellation policy %>"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCancelation" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_h2" Text='<%# Eval("CancellationPolicyText") %>' Visible="false"> </asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%}
            %>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="shoow" style="width: 650px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; display: none"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: As a good advice, indent your code...

Comment: Can you edit your question to better format your code, it's a bit diffcult to read. Especailly with all the leading spaces

Comment: the problem with my issue i in data list i have hyperlink when i click on it in open the first element (td) only, why.